# Load .html into WebView from iOS app Resources?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I have an HTML file (`webview.html`, for now) with relative links to images and `.js` files. I need to load it, and those linked resources into an iOS app's WKWebView.  All the files are stored in `Resources/Non-Localized/`.

I'm attempting to load the files using the following code during `viewDidLoad()`:

```
print("loadWebView: Bundle.main = ", Bundle.main); // This prints
if let htmlUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "webview", withExtension: "html") {
    print("htmlUrl = ", htmlUrl)  // Doesn't print
    webView.load(URLRequest.init(url: htmlUrl))
}
```

The app loads without error, but also without the contents in the webview.
I get the first print statement, but not the second, indicating something is wrong with my URL or resource bundle configuration.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to do anything in XCode to add these files to the project? Where should I be looking for error messages that will hint me in the correct direction in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the file to the Project. I did this by simply dragging the Finder file icon to the project tree in Xcode.

Alternatively (and my final solution), I dragged the parent directory's icon, making a folder reference, and then added `subdirectory` parameter to `.url(forResource...)`.

I'm still working on getting informative errors out of the WebView.